# CyberSource order gets stuck 'In Checkout', never completes

Tags: 6, ubercart, payment-gateways

I am using CyberSource, with ubercart 2.6. I am using the CS test server.
When I make a payment, everything goes through, but the order gets stuck in 'In checkout' when viewing the status at '/admin/store/orders/sort/all'.

In watchdog, I receive the following error:
Receiving invalid payment notification at URL for order ##

Does anyone know what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue: In uc_cybersource.module there is a line in function `uc_cybersource_hop_form($form_state, $order)` that reads

```
$data['orderPage_version'] = '4';
```

It needs to be changed to the current orderPage version (as of this writing it is 7).

```
$data['orderPage_version'] = '7';
```

This should definitely be documented somewhere!